# How can i integrate Liquibase with Jenkins for continuous deployment for Snowflake warehouse?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jenkins-plugins, liquibase, cicd

I am creating a Schema Change Management workflow with liquibase for my Snowflake data warehouse. The jenkins plugin available for this is 3 year old and i will not be able to use it. Is there any new liquibase-jenkins plugin release coming? or is there any other way to integrate the two tools?

i tried this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/liquibase-runner/ , but this is 3 year old.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a good idea in this use case would be not to rely on Jenkins in common and on 3rd party plugins in particular. Liquibase [provides a Docker container](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-liquibase-and-docker.html) with preinstalled drivers and clients (including Snowflake) that could be integrated with Jenkins pipelines or any other tool.